# Android Recording like Snapchat/InstagramStory

Tags: android, kotlin, video, camera, record

I would like to know how does Snapchat and/or Instagram capture they videos.

I'm currently working on an android (Kotlin) application where I'm showing a preview of my front camera and at the same time I'm displaying some kind of filters on it.

I've tried to capture the whole screen where I'm displaying the preview but all i got is a black screen and the elements of the view.
I've also tried to record a video but, obviously, the filters are not appearing there.

I've tried things like mediaRecorder, Pixelcopy... but still haven't figured it out what is the correct approach.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Question is what would be the correct approach to record a video with effects (like instagram story or snapchat) in an android application?